# XML Extra free space

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Good day, in general is a problem, I work with XML through C# `XMLdocument`, after saving that "document", there is such a thing:

`<Name></Name>`

After saving:

```
<Name>
</Name>
```

How to remove extra spaces?  I've tried: `doc.PreserveWhitespace=true;`  before saving and before loading. The result is not one that removes all spaces. XML document (large volume) become visually unreadable.
**I have already tried, same result. And need Encoding windows-1251** Why XmlDocument do this bad thing? That free or whitespace important for me and my "program".
the problem is solved. thank you all

Comment: What are you viewing the XML in after you save the document? Any chance that it is doing the formatting for you?

Comment: This XML document is used to load the database after saving in my program, the base of an error.The document becomes unreadable. It is necessary that the formatting was retained positions of nodes after loading and saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. You've got to help control the formatting options when you save the document:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using (var wr = new XmlTextWriter(fileName))
{
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    doc.Save(wr);
}
```

Or you can fine-tune it further with `XmlWriterSettings`:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = false,
    NewLineChars = String.Empty
};
using (var wr = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings))
{
    wr.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    doc.Save(wr);
}
```